# Torsion and Curvature in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

in Landau's book, *field theory*, the famous physicist stated, "Because of equivalence principle， there should be a 'Galileo' frame, in which the Christoffel symbols should be zero, thus the torsion zero. If in one coordinates, the torsion is zero, then it's zero in any coordinates."

My question is are the following:

1. Are there any limitations upon allowed transformation between coordinates? For example smooth?

I've just learned manifolds. Can the two coordinates be viewed as coordinates of one point of the space-time manifold in two different open set. Thus being smooth is the only thing required?

2.In this so called 'Galileo' frame, the Curvature is also zero. Then shouldn't the curvature tensor is also zero in any other coordinates? If so, why Landau just made statements about torsion, omitting curvature?

Comment: The *Galileo frame* is one in which the Christoffel symbols are zero. These are also known as [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). However just because the Christoffel symbols are zero does not mean the curvature is zero. The Christoffel symbols are not tensors so they are not coordinate invariant. It is always possible to choose coordinates in which they are zero even when the Riemann tensor is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification for the concept 'Galileo frame', which I've misunderstood since long. Are the Christoffel symbols only zero in the affinity of a fixed point?

Comment: Generally it is only possible to make all the Christoffel symbols zero at a point.